# Help on derivative: $\frac {d(\sec^x \theta - \tan^x \theta)} {dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, trigonometry

As it says in the title:

Could anyone help me with this? It's required to solve a limit problem but I'm a little confused right now.

$$\frac {d(\sec^x \theta - \tan^x \theta)} {dx}$$

Sorry I'm not v sure how to code the integral, this is my 3rd question ever posted [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxvhZ.png) :(

The trigo functions are raised to the power of $x$, while the angle is $\theta$. It's best if the solution has some sort of $\ln$ function inside.

Comment: What integral?  Is $\theta$ a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=a^x$ for some constant $x$. Then $y = e^{\ln(a^x)} = e^{x\ln(a)}$. Differentiating with respect to $x$ we get ${dy\over dx} = e^{\ln(a^x)}{d(x\ln(a))\over dx} = \ln(a)e^{\ln(a^x)} = \ln(a)a^x$. Since $a$ was any constant, this in particular holds for $a = \sec(\theta)$ and $b = \tan(\theta)$. So in this problem, the result is

$${d(\sec^x(\theta) -  \tan^x(\theta))\over dx} = \ln(\sec(\theta))\sec^x(\theta) +  \ln(\tan(\theta))\tan^x(\theta)$$

Comment: negative sign in between

Comment: Ahh yes thank you I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\theta$ is a constant, we rewrite $$\sec^x \theta = e^{\ln (\sec^x \theta)} = e^{x(\ln (\sec \theta))}$$

Then we take derivative:

$$\frac d{dx}\sec^x\theta = \frac d{dx} e^{x(\ln (\sec \theta))} = \ln (\sec \theta)e^{x(\ln (\sec \theta))} = \ln (\sec \theta)\sec^x\theta$$

It follows from the general case: $$\dfrac d{dx}a^x = \dfrac d{dx}e^{x \ln a} = (\ln a) e^{\ln a} = a^x \ln a$$

Can you differentiate $\tan^x \theta$ now?

Comment: Do you have to code the trigo functions and calculus functions in order for them to show?

Answer (score 1):

Let constants $$\sec \theta = p,\; \tan \theta =q $$

By the Chain Rule (in effect using log differentiation )

$$ \frac{d(p^x)}{dx}= p^x \log p \; etc. $$

So the derivative is

$$ p^x \log p- q^x \log q $$

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have some constant raised to the power of $x$, say $a$, then
$$\frac{d}{dx}a^x=a^x\ln a$$
More generally, it may be of interest that
$$\frac{d}{dx}a^{kx}=a^{kx}k\ln a$$
You may want to try proving these derivatives by using the chain rule. In your case, as the angle $\theta$ isn't a variable the trig functions are simply constants; hence the rule above applies to each.